# Change color of attributes javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I currently trying to change the color of the div when onclick the  but fail , i using "postid" instead of using id and class cause it need to change the color of the div that onclick only

```js
$(function () {
  $('.like').click(function () { likeFunction(this); });

});


function likeFunction(caller) {
  var postId = caller.parentElement.getAttribute('postid');
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "rate.php",
      data: 'Action=LIKE&PostID=' + postId,
      success: function () {}
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="post" postid="10">
    <input type="button" class='like' value="LikeButton" /> </input>

</div>
```

Comment: How are you trying? I see 2 HTML elements, but no script. Can you show your attempts?

Comment: Please provide the code, what you have tried, I only see HTML.

Comment: What have you tried with your `JavaScript` so far?

Comment: Have you tried using [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) attributes instead?

Answer (score 1):

You can reference `$(this)` in your likeFunction, and use a class to change the color.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.like').click(likeFunction);
});

function likeFunction() {
  $(this).addClass('clicked')
  var postId = $(this).parent().attr('postid');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "rate.php",
    data: 'Action=LIKE&PostID=' + postId,
    success: function() {}
  });
}
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post" postid="10">
  <input type="button" class='like' value="LikeButton" /> </input>

</div>
```